# saving a input value in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a dictionary, that translates english to swedish, and would like to let the user add new words to it. However, despite my attempts at updating the dictionary with the input, the values of the dictionary always reset to the base case when re-running Python. Check out the code:

```
dictionary = {"merry": "god",   #base dictionary
              "christmas": "jul",
              "and": "och",
             "happy": "gott",
              "new": "nytt",
              "year": "ar"
}

def add():  #Prompting user to add words to the dictionary, by asking how many he wants to add ( 0 is an option)
    while True:
        try:
            a = int(input("How many words do you want to add to the dictionary? "))
            if a >= 0:
                break
            else:   #don't want negative values
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("Not valid ")
    return a
for i in range (add()):
    key_i = input(f"Enter english word {i + 1}: ")
    value_i = input("Enter translation: ")
    dictionary[key_i] = value_i

print(dictionary)
```

Comment: In addition to saving your dictionary as a json as recommended by @/DSC above, you may want to read about pickle, https://realpython.com/python-pickle-module/

Comment: Use pickle package to save the dictionary and reload it everytime u start a rerun

Answer (score 0):

Try using this class:

```
import pickle

class Logger:
        
    def save(self, obj, path):
        with open(path, 'wb') as logfile:
            pickle.dump(obj, logfile)
    
    def load(self, path):
        with open(path, 'rb') as logfile:
            new_instance = pickle.load(logfile)
        return new_instance
```

Then, at the beginning of your code create a new instance of the Logger and load (if already existing) the saved dictionary:

```
path = "./path/to/your/local/directory/" #change this with the path where you have previously saved your dictionary logs
logger = Logger()
dictionary = logger.load(path)
```

Then, at the end of your code, create a new instance of the logs and save them:

```
logger.save(dictionary, path)
```

Comment: thanks, and how should I define the variable path? it prompts a nameError

Comment: That is just a string such as "path/to/your/local/directory" where you want to save your dictionary logs